# Как в таблице Quasar сгруппировать данные

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar.js

Фронтенд на Vue + Quasar

Есть массив данных:

```
<target>: Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
    0: Object { id: 1, client: "Цветы России", month: "03", … }
      client: "Цветы России"
      id: 1
      month: "03"
      year: 2022
      oborot: 546456

    1: Object { id: 7, client: "Цветы России", month: "06", … }
      client: "Цветы России"
      id: 7
      month: "06"
      oborot: 567567
      year: 2021

      2: Object { id: 10, client: "Цветы России", month: "03", … }
        client: "Цветы России"
        id: 10
        month: "03"
        year: 2021
        oborot: 65856756

      3: Object { id: 6, client: "Тверь", month: "01", … }
        client: "Тверь"​
        id: 6
        month: "01"
        ​​​year: 2022
        oborot: 786786​​​

      4: Object { id: 8, client: "Тверь", month: "06", … }
        client: "Тверь"​​
        id: 8​​​
        month: "06"​​​
        year: 2021
        oborot: 6752222.44

      5: Object { id: 2, client: "Томск", month: "03", … }
        client: "Томск"​​
        id: 2
        month: "03"
        ​​​year: 2022
        oborot: 333333

      6: Object { id: 3, client: "Чита", month: "03", … }
        client: "Чита"
        id: 3
        month: "03"
        year: 2022
        oborot: 777665

      7: Object { id: 5, client: "Чита", month: "01", … }
        client: "Чита"
        id: 5
        month: "01"
        year: 2022
        oborot: 675675
```

Возможно ли сгруппировать эти данные таким образом, чтобы в таблице (QTable) в столбцы встали месяцы, а в строки клиенты с их оборотами в данных месяцах (как на скриншоте)
[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напрямик такие данные QTable не скормить. Сначала надо привести их в требуемый формат, подготовить строки по каждому клиенту. Отдельная проблема здесь — двухстрочный заголовок, но всё решаемо.